# Redirect to a Url is not working after POST response

Tags: node.js, koa, shopify-app

I am sending a post request from the frontend and i am getting a response with a confirmation url, i want to redirect to that url, but it is not doing so

iam using:-
koajs as framework

**backend code**:-

```
router.post("/api/pricing/:token/:shop", koaBody(), async (ctx) => {
  try {
    let shopname = await ctx.params.shop;
    let dataBody = await ctx.request.body;
    let bodyStringyfy = JSON.stringify(dataBody);
    let tokenjson = await ctx.params.token;

    const options = {
      method: "POST",
      body: bodyStringyfy,
      headers: {
        "X-Shopify-Access-Token": tokenjson,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    let url = `https://${shopname}/admin/api/2021-01/recurring_application_charges.json`;
    await fetch(url, options)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        ctx.redirect(
          `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${res.recurring_application_charge.confirmation_url}`
        );
      });

  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
});
```

Comment: How are you calling this API?

Comment: @Evert await axios
      .post(`/api/pricing/${shoptoken}/${shopname}`, body) from frontend

Comment: What do you expect axios to do with the redirect?

Comment: my app is inside of an iframe. On api call i should receive a url and i want to redirect to that url not inside of the iframe redirect from the top

Comment: If you do an fetch/xmlhttprequest, redirects don't apply to the browser they are embedded in. They are completely separate HTTP requests. Only if a user *navigates* to a url that redirects (inside an iframe or not) a browser will respect the redirect. You should probably just read the `Location` HTTP response header and then manually update `document.location`